# Declaring Qt class in header file

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, forward-declaration

I am reading book about using Qt5 (author Max Schlee), and I noticed that some examples have declared existing Qt class in the header file, for example like this:

```
class QProgressBar;
```

So, my question – why don't we just include the header file `QProgressBar` without declaring `class QProgressBar;` in our header file?

Comment: The main reason for not wanting to do that is that you should be using child objects/widgets by value, and then you have to include relevant headers anyway - you can't use forward-declared classes. Most of Qt examples use pointers to child objects and child widgets with abandon, and completely unnecessarily...

Answer (score 8):

It's not about Qt, it's c++.

It's called forward declaration.

Basically in the `.h` you just say that `QProgressbar` is a class and do not complain about the fact that it's not defined. Then in the `.cpp` file you put the header, so that at compile time, the compiler will have everything well defined.

This can save compile time, as `#include` force the compiler to open more files and process more input.

This can also save on unnecessary recompilation. `#include` can force your code to be recompiled more often, due to unrelated changes in the header.

Of course on large projects you can have drawbacks.

You can find more [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration).